# Using offscreen buffering on a Virtualbox machine with Java3D

Tags: java, opengl, virtualbox, java-3d

I am trying to execute a Java 3D application on VirtualBox (compatible up to OpenGL 2.1, tested with GLViewer)

The code is, of course, much larger, but if I execute this (or any other code getting the Canvas to render):

```
javax.media.j3d.GraphicsConfigTemplate3D template = new javax.media.j3d.GraphicsConfigTemplate3D();
// device is just the panel's device. 
GraphicsConfiguration preferredConfiguration = device.getBestConfiguration(template);
Canvas3D canvasTest = new Canvas3D(preferredConfiguration, true);
String glVersionTest = (String)canvasCheat.queryProperties().get("native.version");
System.out.println(glVersionTest);
```

This code works perfectly on my host computer. However, when it is executed on VirtualBox it crashes with the following message:

```
Java 3D ERROR : OpenGL 1.2 or better is required (GL_VERSION=1.1)
```

If the canvas is not offscreen (changing the second argument to false), the code executes correctly, and informs that the current native version is Chromium OpenGL 2.1 (as expected).

Is VirtualBox not compatible with Java 3D in this manner, or am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: At first, please confirm that you use Java3D >= 1.6.0 pre-12. Secondly, the error message above appears when the pipeline tries to use Microsoft GDI renderer (which supports only OpenGL 1.1) instead of the manufacturer's OpenGL driver.

Comment: Thanks for that. I assume you mean the jogAmp version rather than the java3d.java.net, right? I had not tried that yet. Thanks.

Comment: Sun Microsystems put Java3D on hold in January 2008. Yes it's time to use the only actively maintained version of Java3D.

Comment: While it did not solve the problem, this version gives way better error messages, and seems to perform better. I'll probably upgrade the version anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Some other JogAmp users already use VirtualBox, you should ask some help on the official JogAmp IRC channel. There is a way of using hardware acceleration with VirtualBox without falling back to the crappy GDI renderer for sure.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Will go back to it in a couple days. It is definetely a VB problem now, so I will do that if I cannot fix it.